# Elastic Search JAVA API

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am trying to code a java application which will be processing requests on elastic search server. I have referred to the official documentation about [JAVA API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack-overview/current/api-java.html) but i am not able to do so because the compiler (Intellij idea) is not recognizing some classes of the code and displaying error.

Do you have any idea what to do now and where to start now?

Comment: which build tool (grade/maven) you are using?

Comment: i am using the maven

Answer (score 0):

Hope this might help ,Download the Xpack API [jar](https://artifacts.elastic.co/maven/org/elasticsearch/client/x-pack-transport/6.2.4/x-pack-transport-6.2.4.pom), Then add it to your classpath,
Then add this dependency to your pom file

```
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
     <artifactId>x-pack-transport</artifactId>
     <version>6.2.4</version>
  </dependency>
```

Comment: I have tried adding the latest version dependency to pom file. But it didn't worked for me. Could you refer me some link or article where i can get more help

Comment: what classes are not recogonized in intellij?

Comment: WatchSourceBuilders, PutWatchResponse these classes are not recognized by intellij